# Is there a simple way to create a modal child window that accept keyboard input in Win32 SDK?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, keyboard, dialog

I'm now writing an Win32 SDK application. I need to create a modal child window for select from several options. My design is: Simply display them on the child window, if user press key 1, the 1st options is selected. other options are the same. After selection is made the child window close self automatically.

My problem is, is there a simple way to create such a child window? I have found two ways, both with some boring steps.

The first way is to create a dialog resource and use DialogBox function. It can easily create a modal child window. But since it is a modal dialog, system has filtered out all keyboard messages. I need to use some special tecs, like message hooking or something, to get these messages.

The second way is to register a class and directly call the CreateWindow(Ex) function. It can easily create a window with keyboard messages. But it seems to set it as a modal dialog is boring. I need to manually disable the parent window, set child window foreground, create a complete message loop for this window, and manually enable the parent window after it destroyed.

I have searched for a simple way to create a window with both of these 2 features. However found no clue apart from these 2 ways above. I'm not sure if this way exists. Can anyone tell me? My thanks for replies.

Comment: Hi, what programming language are you using? Is it C/C++? Also, are you working with Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using C. My compiler is Mingw/gcc 4.6.1. I'm not working in VS. However, I think it wouldn't change the behavor.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion working with the Win32 SDK is really complicated especially when you are creating a GUI (normally even creating a simple window can be challenge). Therefore would recommend the following to you:

1. Microsoft has a very neat API called MFC that comes with Visual Studio (I don't know if you can use MFC outside Visual Studio) and that has several C++ classes that wrap the Windows SDK methods, making things a lot easier for you. Furthermore Visual Studio lets you use a drag and drop interface to create your GUI (which I find really useful).
2. You can use a third party API to create your GUI elements like GTK or QT. Both are written in C/C++ and are very good APIs. Hopefully they will make your life easier when designing GUIs.
3. If using C/C++ is not a requirement for you, then I would strongly recommend that you use a higher level language like Java or C# to develop your application. I think that designing your GUI with them should prove a lot less troublesome that doing the same thing in C/C++.

Comment: Thanks ^ ^. I knew about MFC and C# WinForm (although I don't like MFC), and I have already implement it by C#. This application is simple since it is mainly for study win32 api, as I have a little bit OCD about executable size and performance=_=;;; Anyway if no simple ways found at last, I'll try the second one.